# Java jbdc get an error No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://ortal-pc\SQLEXPRESS

Tags: java, jdbc

Im trying to connect to **sql** from **java** as following:

```
       Properties properties = new Properties();
         // properties.put("user", "Ortal");
        //  properties.put("password", "");
          properties.put("characterEncoding", "ISO-8859-1");
          properties.put("useUnicode", "true");
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://ortal-pc\\SQLEXPRESS";

          try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver").newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          Connection c = null;
        try {
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I added the jar to the project lib and added it to the build path
When Im running the project I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://ortal-pc\SQLEXPRESS
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at Rent.openConnection(Rent.java:42)
at Rent.<init>(Rent.java:15)
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: what database `mysql` or `hsqldb` are you using.

Comment: You are mixing information from *three* different DBMS here. The name `SQLEXPRESS` is usually used for **Microsoft SQL Server Express**. The prefix `jdbc:mysql` denotes a JDBC connection to a **MySQL** database and the classname `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver` indicates that you might be using **HSQLDB** (although the correct class name would be `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver`). So what are you *really* using? Once you know that check the manual for your JDBC driver to get the correct classname and URL syntax. And you don't "*connect to **SQL***". SQL is just a *query language* it is not a DBMS product.

Comment: What jar did you add?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sqlserver you connection string should look like this `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=MyUserName;password=*****`

And driver for that is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc
```

Comment: i added the username and the password: properties.put("user", "Ortal");
      properties.put("password", "12345678"); and  it doesnt work

Comment: puting properties for username and password is ok thats what i wanted to say.

Comment: Anyway use following string if you are using sqlserver.   jdbc:sqlserver://{computer-name}\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=YourDatabase;integratedSecurity=true